# How to solve an inequality one of its sides is an absolute function

Tags: inequality

I want to solve this inequality $\left| x-3\right|\le 4$, and I know that it's solved like this: $$\because-4 \le x-3 \le 4 \iff-1 \le x\le 7 \\ \therefore S.S=\left[-1, 7\right]$$, but I want to know why I solve it like that, I have tried to say: $$\because \left| x-3\right| \le 4 \\ \therefore x-3 \le \pm 4$$ and this is wrong of course, then I have changed it to an equation and solved it, $S.S=\{1,7\}$, but I don't know how to connect it with the inequality, so how can I deduce the way I solved the inequality by?

Comment: Are you asking for an intuitive explanation of why the first method works?

Comment: I think I have intuition about it, the problem is that I only understand it by intuition and yes I want to know why it works, and an extra intuitive explanation won't be bad.

Comment: Just read the inequality out loud: "The distance from $x$ to 3 is at most 4." as a piece of extra intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be interpreted like this.

$|x-3| \le 4$ has two possible cases:

- $x-3 \ge 0$, then $|x-3| = x-3$ and the inequality yields $x-3 \le 4 \iff x \le 7$. Now combining $x-3 \ge 0 \iff x \ge 3$ and $x \le 7$, you get $x \in [3,7]$.
- $x-3 < 0$, then $|x-3| = -(x-3)$ and the inequality yields $-(x-3) \le 4 \iff x \ge -1$. Now combining $x-3 < 0 \iff x < 3$ and $x \ge -1$ you get $x \in [-1,3)$

Combining both cases you get
$$
x \in [3,7] \cup [-1,3) = [-1,7]
$$

Comment: thank you very much this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with the definition of the absolute value for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ being $\vert x \vert = x$, for $x \geq 0$ and $\vert x \vert = -x$ for $x < 0$. Thus in your case, if $x-3 \geq 0$, we have $\vert x- 3 \vert = x-3 \leq 4$, that is $x \leq 7$. Now if $x-3 <0$, then $\vert x-3 \vert = -(x-3)= -x+3 \leq 4$, so $-1 \leq x$.

Comment: I really have to thank you, I can't upvote your answer because of the reputation, but it helped my.

Comment: you are welcome